# Is it possible to get an AIR 3.0 Captive Runtime app into the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, air, store

Is it possible to get an AIR 3.0 Captive Runtime app into the Mac App Store?  How would you do that?

Comment: Hello William, [Here](http://pigsels.com/2012/04/air-app-store-publishing-guide/) you can find pretty thorough article how to upload an AIR app in the Mac App-store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a link](http://pigsels.com/2012/04/air-app-store-publishing-guide/) where you can find pretty thorough article how to upload an AIR app in the Mac App-store.

Comment: Heitara -- that worked!  Our AIR app is now in the Mac App Store!: [http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cell-imaging/id474504116?ls=1&mt=12]

Comment: I'm glad that you manage to publish your app. It's a nice one. I would recommend to disable the resizing of the window. The content of the app is optimized for certain size, so just stick to it.The user should mind about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple of steps to doing this. First, and this is what I have found to be the easiest solution, is to build an AIR Intermediate file from Flash Builder 4.5. Once that file is built, use the adt command line packager with the "-target bundle" flag to sign and package the a Mac OSX application bundle. This will result in a fully working captive runtime application bundle that you can run on OSX. When you have completed the Adobe side of things and have verified that is runs correctly you can move on to the Apple side.

I would recommend you reference Apple's developer documentation for this here: [Submit Your Application using Application Loader](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html). You will need to use both the "codesign" and "productbuild" commands on the application bundle you created from Adobe's packager. When done, you should now be able to use Apple's Application Loader to submit the package to the Mac App Store.

I have not yet tried to sign the AIRI package with my Apple certificate, so I'm not sure if that would work, since I have both an Thawte cert for Air apps and the Apple issued one. This would take further testing.

Comment: Yes, I think I would do the following steps:

1) Repackage the SWF into a .app using "adt -target bundle"
2) codesign the .app file
3) productbuild the .app file
4) Upload the app.

It's just pretty tedious and if I mess up on any of these steps, it takes time to figure out where I went wrong.  So, if anyone already knows how, that would be helpful!

Comment: @William Umm, that is how. The only thing I have had no issue double signing the file once with my AIR code signing cert, and the app with the apple developer profile cert as the document I linked to explains. The only ambiguous thing is if you can use the Apple issued cert for both steps. I've never tried because I've had to code sign the app and an AIR package. These steps are not very time consuming, I often work with 1GB+ AIR packages and this takes just a few minutes. If you are using more normal size files the time should be nominal.

Comment: I posted an example on how to use ADT on Andrew Trice's blog: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/ .  Figuring this out was pretty challenging.  I did manage to package the app to upload to the Mac App Store, but Application Loader returns: _Invalid Signature -- the nested app bundle ${bundleName} [MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework] is not signed, the signature is invalid, or it is not signed with an Apple submission certificate..._  I think this is because I signed the .AIRI file with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I'm having trouble signing the .AIRI file with the Apple certificate.   I get the following error: _Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer._.  I searched the forums and found that the root Apple certificate is needed to be included in the .p12 file.  A number of people seemed to work through this using Windows, but selecting all 3 in Mac doesn't seem to do the trick.  I am determined to get this Flash app into the Mac App Store!

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work on a Mac, but I created a .p12 that included the entire chain via Windows.  But now, when I use ADT, I get the following error: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space_

Comment: I also tried signing the .AIRI file by typing: 'adt -sign -storetype KeychainStore -alias '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyName' -providerName Apple -storepass password MyApp.airi MyApp.air', but I get this error: 'KeychainStore Ignored Exception: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
unexpected failure: null'

Comment: I'm still hoping to do this -- has anyone put an AIR app into the Mac App Store?

Comment: I am still hoping for a solution to this.  Anyone?

Comment: @William Grand, you can just upload this ${bundleName} [MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework] is not signed is only warning.

Comment: Hi Heitara, can you rephrase that?  I don't understand what you mean, thanks.