# Adobe AIR 3.0 - Creating Captive Runtime .APP file using ADT

Tags: air, adobe, runtime, adt

Can someone tell me how to create a .APP file that using the AIR3.0 captive runtime?

So far, I have the following:

adt -package pkcs12 -keystore MyPersonalCertificate.p12  -target bundle pkcs12 -keystore CertFromAppleWebsite.p12  CellImaging.app Protocols_Large-app.xml ./xml Protocols_Large.swf ./Category_Icons ./AppIconsForPublish

Andrew Trice touches on it here: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/

So far, I get the following error:

> Signing options required to package from descriptor and fileset

Ultimately, I plan to put this into the Mac App Store, but first I have to create the .app file!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot "-storetype":

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore MyPersonalCertificate.p12 -target bundle pkcs12 -keystore CertFromAppleWebsite.p12 CellImaging.app Protocols_Large-app.xml ./xml Protocols_Large.swf ./Category_Icons ./AppIconsForPublish
```

Be wary though, ordering is important:
http://www.andymoore.ca/2013/06/adobe-air-error-on-exe-bundle-package/

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find a solution to your problem, here's how I do it.

Create a signed release build (air) file and then run the following command in the terminal:

`[path to the sdk]/bin/adt -package -target bundle [choose a path and filename where your bundled application is saved] [path to the air file]`

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response -- no, this process has come to a standstill and it almost appears as though no one has been able to get an AIR app into the Mac App Store.  I have not been able to sign the .AIRI file with an Apple Certificate, and the Mac App Store won't allowed a self-signed app.  More here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815115/is-it-possible-to-get-an-air-3-0-captive-runtime-app-into-the-mac-app-store]

Comment: Although, I just noticed that Zinc includes a process to get apps into the Mac App Store.  But, I'm not familiar with it.