# Packaging Flash Builder 4.6 Mobile App as a Desktop App (with Air runtime)?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

Okay, so I have this application that is basically the ubiqutous page turning component you can find online, but modified for mobile.  It's for kid's storybooks.  It's a mobile flex application in FlashBuilder 4.6.  When I export release build for my mobile project, I see an option for desktop .air packaging rather than mobile.  Works and looks great....but you can't sell a .air file on Mac App Store.  I want to bundle the air runtime to create a  .app, which hopefully I can get on the app store.  However, this option is not available in a mobile project.  I've tried figuring it out via commandline...

java -jar adt.jar -package -keystore ./jamesabrannan_cert_development.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -target bundle ShortBook.app ShortBook-app.xml ShortBook.swf

but that results in.... no such file /Users/jamesabrannan/Documents/test/ShortBook.app

So then I saw that perhaps some of the google results might be wrong/outdated and I was actually simply supposed to indicate the folder the app was to be created in, okay, so....

java -jar adt.jar -package -keystore ./jamesabrannan_cert_development.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -target bundle . ShortBook-app.xml ShortBook.swf

But that results in....

Files "/Users/jamesabrannan/Documents/test/ShortBook-app.xml" and "/Users/jamesabrannan/Documents/test/ShortBook-app.xml" have conflicting package paths: /Users/jamesabrannan/Documents/test/ShortBook-app.xml

What I want to do is take my mobile application and package it with the OS X runtime for adobe air.  It must be possible, but I'll be darned if I can figure it out.  Looks like I have AIR 2.6, or whatever is standard in FlashBuilder 4.6

I'm trying to avoid creating a desktop app, adding the mobile framework, and then transfering my code to it.

Any help would be appreciated.  This would be a great boon, as some tablet apps would be totally applicable - with a few slight modifications - on a desktop.

Thanks,
James A. Brannan
Brannan Technical Solutions LLC
www.floopiebooks.com

Comment: have you tried this first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815115/is-it-possible-to-get-an-air-3-0-captive-runtime-app-into-the-mac-app-store

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project, export release and choose air desktop package
see [this reference](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/07/29/exporting-air-mobile-apps-as-desktop-apps/)